# Dmp file import create triggers error

Tags: database, oracle, import, oracle11g, export

I've taken a full database backup from one server to be moved to another using the following command (both using Oracle 11g):

```
exp SYSTEM/password@db1 full=y grants=y rows=y file=backup.dmp
```

And now when I want to import it into the other database using this:

```
imp SYSTEM/password file=backup.dmp fromuser=scott touser=scott
```

I first get an error related to database link:

```
Create Database Link Failed. ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.
```

If someone could explain why the imp command tried to link my new database to the source one which is not connected that would be helpful.
But otherwise that's not my main issue...

After that first error it continues with the import and imports all the rows and tables then at the end I get a series of errors related to 'CREATE TRIGGER's with error

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Am I missing something in my import parameters?

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to have privileges to create a database link, Please run this as sys user

```
SQL> grant create database link to scott;

 Grant succeeded.
```

Then reimport the dumpfile, the triggers are failing because the related tables are not existing which i'm assuming the database link would be used to create the tables in the first place.

if you only want the scott user to be export then no need to connect to sys,
this will work,

```
export command

exp scott/pwd@db1 file=backup.dmp log=backup_log.log owner=scott 

import command

imp scott/pwd@db? file=backup.dmp log=imp_backup.log full=y
```

Comment: I've granted database link and now the privileges error doesn't come up but I'm still getting the table/view does not exist errors when the triggers are being created.

Comment: are the two scott schemas in different database ? if so then you would need the tables also, using rows=y will only get you data but not table structure, it would be better to use owner=scott in your exp command and then try the import that will get all your table structure and data as well

Comment: I tried to use FULL=y but still got the same errors. 
I don't have access to the source database anymore. I just have this full database backup I took using:
exp SYSTEM/pass@dbname FULL=y FILE="C:\backup.dmp" GRANTS=y ROWS=y log="C:\backup.log"

And now I want to import everything from a user to a user with the same name I created on the destination database.
It's not only importing the rows, it's creating table structures as well but not the ones related to the triggers.

Comment: the error which says " Table does not exist", is that table present in the logfile ? if it is there then it will definitely import if its not there in the logfile then its not in the dumpfile.

Comment: I looked for that table name in the export log file and it's not there. But how is this possible if I did a full backup?

Comment: in that case, if the table is not in the log file that means the table doesn't exist in the database , if it would have existed  it would have been in the backup for sure.

Comment: in the logfile look for this sentence,  ". about to export SCOTT's tables via Conventional Path ..." the table if it was under scotts owner ship should below that line,

Comment: But it's not :/... I don't understand how the trigger belongs to SCOTT but is on tables that don't exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75782/discussion-between-anudeepks-and-tarek-merachli).